# convex hull function in matlab

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, matlab

Is there any way to compute the convex hull of a finite set of points in Matlab and gives the half-space representation as its result?

I usually use a toolbox called MPT developed at ETHZ Zurich, but its results are not stable, and my problem requires a high precision with respect to high dimension of the points ( >= 4 ).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the half-space representation. Can't you just calculate that yourself from the returned points?

```
>> lookfor hull
convhull                       - Convex hull of a set of points in 2D/3D space
convhulln                      - N-D Convex hull.
qhull                          - Copyright information for Qhull.
bwconvhull                     - Generate convex hull image from binary image.
```

Comment: [convhulln](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhulln.html): "`K = convhulln(X)` returns the indices `K` of the points in `X` that comprise the facets of the convex hull of `X`. `X` is an `m`-by-`n` array representing `m` points in `n`-dimensional space. If the convex hull has `p` facets then `K` is `p`-by-`n`." Yep, you can definitely compute the half-spaces from that.

Comment: Thanks so much, i saw it in the help of matlab, but my knowledge is limited, i did not really understand how to come from this matrix of indices to the half-space representation. Could you kindly help me to clarify it?